# Range not working in for loop

Tags: html, django-templates, jinja2

My for loop is not working and I'm not sure why.

This is the loop:

```
{% for i in range({{text|length}} + {{images|length}}) %}
```

`text` and `images` are querysets I have passed to the template from the view.

The error I am getting is:

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for i in range({{text|length}} + {{images|length}})

This doesn't make sense to me, as it looks to me as if this does follow the format suggested by the error.

Answer (score -1):

```
{% for i in range((text|length) + (images|length)) %}
```

That should fix it. The {{}} are used for another purpose. I have my own problem in jinja2 and haven't used it before. My loop is:

```
{% for i in range(string1|length) %}
```

and it works

Comment: I have tried this and it has made no difference. I get the exact same error.
`django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for i in range(text|length + images|length)`

Comment: You also have {% endfor %}? and also maybe try ((text|length) + (images|length)). Also do you know if images|length and text|length is defined? try just display {{text|length}} and {{images|length}} somewhere and see what it displays

Comment: I have `{%  endfor%}`. I have tried displaying `{{text|length}}` and `{{images|length}}` and they both works fine. I have tried `range((text|length) + (images|length))` and get the same error as before.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53180287/jinja-django-for-loop-range-not-working) and how it was solved. It might help you. It seems not to be supported by django.