# Jinja / Django for loop range not working

Tags: django-templates, jinja2

I'm building a django template to duplicate images based on an argument passed from the view; the template then uses Jinja2 in a for loop to duplicate the image.

BUT, I can only get this to work by passing a list I make in the view.  If I try to use the jinja range, I get an error ("Could not parse the remainder: ...").

Reading [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595150/range-not-working-in-for-loop), I swear I'm using the right syntax.

**template**

```
{% for i in range(variable) %}
    <img src=...>
{% endfor %}
```

I checked the variable I was passing in; it's type int.  Heck, I even tried to get rid of the variable (for testing) and tried using a hard-coded number:

```
{% for i in range(5) %}
    <img src=...>
{% endfor %}
```

I get the following error:

> Could not parse the remainder: '(5)' from 'range(5)'

If I pass to the template a list in the arguments dictionary (and use the list in place of the range statement), it works; the image is repeated however many times I want.

**What am I missing?**  The docs on Jinja ([for loop](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#for) and [range](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#list-of-global-functions)) and the previous link all tell me that this should work with range and a variable.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates). The range function is not supported by Django template, unfortunately.

Comment: Errrrrg.  Thanks, Franndy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Soooo.... based on Franndy's comment that this isn't automatically supported by Django, and following their [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates), which leads to [this link](https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/), I found how to write your own filter.

Inside **views.py**:

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_range(value):
    return range(value)
```

Then, inside **template**:

```
{% for i in variable|get_range %}
    <img src=...>
{% endfor %}
```